# How can I create a SQL function with a parameter?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

The following code returns one field, a string, based on the input where it says "28".

```
SELECT data.id, LTRIM(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(name, ', '),',') conc_names
  FROM (
     SELECT id, name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by name) rownumber, COUNT(*) OVER () cnt
      FROM (
         SELECT es.EVENT_ID as id, s.SERVICE_NAME as name FROM DT_SERVICES s
            JOIN DT_EVENT_SERVICE es ON s.SERVICE_ID = es.SERVICE_ID
         WHERE es.EVENT_ID = 28
      )
) data
WHERE rownumber = cnt
START WITH rownumber = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR rownumber = rownumber-1;
```

How can I create a SQL function out of this so that I can pass in whatever number (instead of 28) and the function would return whatever the result of that select turns out to be?

I tried creating one but I keep getting compilation errors.

Current SQL to create function

```
create or replace function "DT_SERVICE_STRING" (id in VARCHAR2)
  return VARCHAR2 is
begin
  DECLARE 
     result VARCHAR(200);
  SELECT data.id, LTRIM(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(name, ', '),',') conc_names
    INTO result
    FROM (
      SELECT id, name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by name) rownumber, COUNT(*) OVER () cnt
      FROM (
        SELECT es.EVENT_ID as id, s.SERVICE_NAME as name FROM DT_SERVICES s
        JOIN DT_EVENT_SERVICE es ON s.SERVICE_ID = es.SERVICE_ID
        WHERE es.EVENT_ID = id
      )
  ) data
  WHERE rownumber = cnt
  START WITH rownumber = 1
  CONNECT BY PRIOR rownumber = rownumber-1;

  return result;
end;​
```

Error:
Compilation failed,line 7 (15:22:21)
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following: begin function pragma procedure subtype type current cursor delete exists prior

Comment: what do you have that is getting compilation errors?

Comment: I am trying to create it as a function in Oracle Apex

Comment: and what does it look like, that isn't working? update your question with your existing but broken code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you want a PL/SQL function that is callable from a SQL statement (you cannot have a function defined in SQL), it sounds like you want something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_conc_names( p_event_id IN dt_event_service.event_id%type )
  RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  l_conc_names VARCHAR2(32676); 
  -- You may want a smaller variable if you know the result will be smaller
BEGIN
  SELECT LTRIM(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(name, ', '),',') conc_names
    INTO l_conc_names
    FROM (
      SELECT id, name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by name) rownumber, COUNT(*) OVER () cnt
        FROM (SELECT es.EVENT_ID as id, s.SERVICE_NAME as name 
                FROM DT_SERVICES s
                     JOIN DT_EVENT_SERVICE es ON s.SERVICE_ID = es.SERVICE_ID
               WHERE es.EVENT_ID = p_event_id )
          ) data
   WHERE rownumber = cnt
   START WITH rownumber = 1
 CONNECT BY PRIOR rownumber = rownumber-1;
  RETURN l_conc_names;
END;
```

Based on the code you just posted, it appears that you just need to get rid of the `DECLARE` and to move the declaration of the local variable `result` before the `BEGIN` and after the `IS`.

Comment: Did. Now I get this: Compilation failed,line 8 (15:27:25)
PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough valuesCompilation failed,line 7 (15:27:25)
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Comment: @antonpug - I updated my answer.  Didn't notice that your `SELECT` statement was selecting two columns.  Since you're only returning one value, I assume that you really only need to select the `conc_names` string.

Comment: Hm, that's strange, the same error persists. And yeah i noticed the two columns myself as well. It keeps telling me Not Enough Values

Answer (score 0):

I think the analytic functions need to be inside the inner inline view and then the outer inline view can select them--that's how I've always done it.  Try this instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_conc_names( p_event_id IN dt_event_service.event_id%type ) 
  RETURN VARCHAR2 
IS 
  l_conc_names VARCHAR2(32676);  
  -- You may want a smaller variable if you know the result will be smaller 
BEGIN 
  SELECT LTRIM(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(name, ', '),',') conc_names 
    INTO l_conc_names 
    FROM ( 
      SELECT id, name, rownumber, cnt 
        FROM (SELECT es.EVENT_ID as id
                    ,s.SERVICE_NAME as name
                    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by name) as rownumber
                    ,COUNT(*) OVER () as cnt
                FROM DT_SERVICES s 
                     JOIN DT_EVENT_SERVICE es ON s.SERVICE_ID = es.SERVICE_ID 
               WHERE es.EVENT_ID = p_event_id ) 
             ) data 
    WHERE rownumber = cnt 
    START WITH rownumber = 1 
    CONNECT BY PRIOR rownumber = rownumber-1; 
  RETURN l_conc_names; 
END;
```